# Как передать скрытое значение при добавлении в базу?

Tags: база-данных, php

В общем, такая задача: при первом запуске страницы `$id` пустой. Так вот пусть я нажимаю сабмит, данные записываются в базу, а `$id = $row[0];` будет равен значению.
Если я снова нажимаю сабмит, то условие `isset($id)` не выполняется. В чем ошибка? Может, как-то по-другому это реализуется?

Comment: скинь пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается так

```
       <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['id'];
} else {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Если есть несколько страниц с разными id, то:

1. Человек в одном браузере сможет просматривать только одну страницу с id.

2. Надо предусмотреть очистку id из сессии (если необходимо).

Comment: Да это правка паспорта, и можно запустить только один одновременно.
Меня это более чем устраивает.  
А про unset($_SESSION['id']); 
при возвращении на главную страницу знаю.
Не первый день замужем.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, $id передается в `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $id ?>" >`?

В таком случае можно проверять на empty:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
if (empty($id)) {
    // Если $id пустой.
}
```

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= ($id) ? $id : '' ?>">
на всякий случай

Comment: Empty от пустоты будет true

    $id = "";
    empty($id)  // true

Comment: А так может быть ошибка на не существование переменной. Или проверять if(!$id)

Comment:     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= ($id) ? $id : '' ?>">
а что делает сей ужс?